# Как выводить данные из базы в карточки, а не в таблицу?

Tags: php, mysql

В данный момент данные базы выводятся в таблицу (код ниже), я же хочу сделать чтобы эти данные выводились в карточки (пример ниже). То есть нужно чтобы каждая строка была карточкой. Как вообще это делается?

```
echo '<table class="ui very basic collapsing celled table">';
            echo '<tr><td><b>Ship ID</b></td><td><b>Name</b></td><td><b>Captain</b></td><td><b>Type</b></td><td><b>Cargo</b></td><td><b>Build</b></td><td><b>Photo</b></td><td>Delete</td></tr>';
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo '<tr><td>'.$row['ship_id'].'</td><td>'.$row['ShipName'].'</td><td>'.$row['CaptainName'].'</td><td>'.$row['ShipType'].'</td><td>'.$row['Cargo'].'</td><td>'.$row['BuildYear'].'</td><td>'.$row['Photo'].'</td></tr>';
            }
        echo '</table>';
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас таблица в цикле выводиться тут:

`echo '<tr><td>'.$row['ship_id'].'</td><td>'.$row['ShipName'].'</td><td>'.$row['CaptainName'].'</td><td>'.$row['ShipType'].'</td><td>'.$row['Cargo'].'</td><td>'.$row['BuildYear'].'</td><td>'.$row['Photo'].'</td></tr>';`

изменить содержимое на div и все. т.е это:

```
echo '<table class="ui very basic collapsing celled table">';
        echo '<tr><td><b>Ship ID</b></td><td><b>Name</b></td><td><b>Captain</b></td><td><b>Type</b></td><td><b>Cargo</b></td><td><b>Build</b></td><td><b>Photo</b></td><td>Delete</td></tr>';
```

и это:

```
echo '</table>';
```

вам не нужно.
Вот я сделал на примере блоков бутстрапа:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {       
   echo'<div class="col-md-3">';
   echo $row['ship_id'].$row['ShipName'].$row['CaptainName'].$row['ShipType'].$row['Cargo'].$row['BuildYear'].$row['Photo'];
   echo '</div>';
}
```

col-md-3 - стилизуйте как вам  хочется. 
тут:

```
$row['ship_id'].$row['ShipName'].$row['CaptainName'].$row['ShipType'].$row['Cargo'].$row['BuildYear'].$row['Photo']
```

тоже, можете дивами обыгрывать как Вам в душе угодно)

Comment: А как именно обыгрывать? Я не совсем понимаю.

Comment: @Fann вы можете сверстать блок, который должен быть, а я php код вставлю вам и объясню на вашем примере.

Comment: Спасибо, уже разобрался.

Answer (score 0):

Избавляемся от лишнего мусора и делаем всё красиво. Про [альтернативный синтаксис](http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) можно почитать в документации

```
<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)): ?>
    <div class="ui card">
        <div class="image">
            <img src="<?=$row['Photo']?>">
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <a class="header"><?=$row['ShipName']?></a>
            <div class="meta">
                <span class="date">Построен в <?=$row['BuildYear']?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="description">
                <?=$row['Cargo']?>
                Тип <?=$row['ShipType']?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="extra content">
            <a>
                <i class="user icon"></i>
                22 Friends
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Я потому и спрашиваю что не понимаю как именно выводить. Вот тут всякие шаблоны этих корточек и все они через div - https://semantic-ui.com/views/card.html

Comment: @Fann исправил ответ. Обратите внимание на короткую запись и на то, что весь этот код НЕ нужно вписывать между ВАШИМИ тегами <?php ?>

Comment: Я работаю с PHP 5.5. Могут ли быть проблемы с вашим решением?

Comment: Проблем не будет.

Comment: И извините, я не совсем понял что Вы имеете в виду - Обратите внимание на короткую запись и на то, что весь этот код НЕ нужно вписывать между ВАШИМИ тегами <?php ?

Comment: кроткая запись - ссылку дал в ответе. Это для изучения и понимания вставок типа `<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)): ?>`. В про последнее... Как бы так объяснить. По сути код этот словно html. И в него вставлены кусочки php кода. Поэтому если у вас код на странице только php и есть начало файла <?php и конец файла ?>, то не нужно мой код  засовывать между этими тегами - будет ошибка. Понятно?

Comment: @Fann Разобрались?

Comment: Да, спасибо Вам!